# Getting bad response using JRAW

Tags: java, python, reddit, praw

I am trying to read data from reddit using java. I am using [JRAW](https://github.com/mattbdean/JRAW).

Here is my code:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        System.out.println('a');
        String username = "dummyName";
        UserAgent userAgent = new UserAgent("crawl", "com.example.crawl", "v0.1", username);
        Credentials credentials = Credentials.script(username, <password>,<clientID>, <client-secret>);
        NetworkAdapter adapter = new OkHttpNetworkAdapter(userAgent);
        RedditClient reddit = OAuthHelper.automatic(adapter, credentials);
        Account me = reddit.me().about();
        System.out.println(me.getName());
        SubmissionReference submission = reddit.submission("https://www.reddit.com/r/diabetes/comments/9rlkdm/shady_insurance_work_around_to_pay_for_my_dexcom/");
        RootCommentNode rcn = submission.comments();
        System.out.println(rcn.getDepth());
        System.out.println();
//        Submission submission1 = submission.inspect();
//        System.out.println(submission1.getSelfText());
//        System.out.println(submission1.getUrl());
//        System.out.println(submission1.getTitle());
//        System.out.println(submission1.getAuthor());
//        System.out.println(submission1.getCreated());
        System.out.println("-----------------------------------------------------------------");
    }
}
```

I am making two requests as of now, first one is `reddit.me().about();` and the second is `reddit.submission("https://www.reddit.com/r/diabetes/comments/9rlkdm/    shady_insurance_work_around_to_pay_for_my_dexcom/");`

The output is:

```
a
[1 ->] GET https://oauth.reddit.com/api/v1/me?raw_json=1
[<- 1] 200 application/json: '{"is_employee": false, "seen_layout_switch": true, "has_visited_new_profile": false, "pref_no_profanity": true, "has_external_account": false, "pref_geopopular": "GL(...)
dummyName
[2 ->] GET https://oauth.reddit.com/comments/https%3A%2F%2Fwww.reddit.com%2Fr%2Fdiabetes%2Fcomments%2F9rlkdm%2Fshady_insurance_work_around_to_pay_for_my_dexcom%2F?sort=confidence&sr_detail=false&(...)
[<- 2] 400 application/json: '{"message": "Bad Request", "error": 400}'
Exception in thread "main" net.dean.jraw.ApiException: API returned error: 400 (Bad Request), relevant parameters: []
    at net.dean.jraw.models.internal.ObjectBasedApiExceptionStub.create(ObjectBasedApiExceptionStub.java:57)
    at net.dean.jraw.models.internal.ObjectBasedApiExceptionStub.create(ObjectBasedApiExceptionStub.java:33)
    at net.dean.jraw.RedditClient.request(RedditClient.kt:186)
    at net.dean.jraw.RedditClient.request(RedditClient.kt:219)
    at net.dean.jraw.RedditClient.request(RedditClient.kt:255)
    at net.dean.jraw.references.SubmissionReference.comments(SubmissionReference.kt:50)
    at net.dean.jraw.references.SubmissionReference.comments(SubmissionReference.kt:28)
    at Main.main(Main.java:36)
Caused by: net.dean.jraw.http.NetworkException: HTTP request created unsuccessful response: GET https://oauth.reddit.com/comments/https%3A%2F%2Fwww.reddit.com%2Fr%2Fdiabetes%2Fcomments%2F9rlkdm%2Fshady_insurance_work_around_to_pay_for_my_dexcom%2F?sort=confidence&sr_detail=false&raw_json=1 -> 400
    ... 6 more
```

As it can been that my first request gives me a response of my username but in the second response i am getting a bad request 400 error.

To check whether my client ID and client secret were working correctly I did the same request using python [PRAW](https://praw.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) library.

```
import praw
from praw.models import MoreComments

reddit = praw.Reddit(client_id=<same-as-in-java>, client_secret=<same-as-in-java>,
                    password=<same-as-in-java>, user_agent='crawl',
                    username="dummyName")


submission = reddit.submission(
    url='https://www.reddit.com/r/redditdev/comments/1x70wl/how_to_get_all_replies_to_a_comment/')

print(submission.selftext)
print(submission.url)
print(submission.title)
print(submission.author)
print(submission.created_utc)
print('-----------------------------------------------------------------')
```

This gives the desired result without any errors so the client secret details must be working.

The only doubt I have is in the user agent creation in java `UserAgent userAgent = new UserAgent("crawl", "com.example.crawl", "v0.1", username);`.

I followed the following [link](https://mattbdean.gitbooks.io/jraw/quickstart.html).

What exactly does the `target platform, the unique ID or the version` mean. I tried to keep the same format as in the link. Also using the same username as in other places. On the other hand the user_agent in python was a string `crawl`.

Please tell me if I am missing anything and what could be the issue.

Thank you

P.S. I want to do this in java. not python.

Comment: The urls used in submission is different in both your examples (not sure if you tried with the same one). In addition, the javadoc shows that to submit, you need to use an "id" (whatever that means, I'm not aware of reddit): https://jitpack.io/com/github/mattbdean/JRAW/v1.0.0/javadoc/index.html. And `PRAW` was not written by the same author, so there is no reason to believe they will use the same arguments for their methods

Comment: I have tried multiple urls for both codes so thats not an issue. Yes, they are written by different authors but are based on the same [api](https://www.reddit.com/dev/api/) but i understand your point. Thank you

Comment: Solved: in JRAW, submission needs a ID which is in the URL. In the above examples the IDs are `9rlkdm` and `1x70wl` respectively. P.s: In PRAW both `id` or `url` can work. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your first query is working the credentials are correct. In JRAW don't give the whole URL but only the id in the submission function.

Change this

```
SubmissionReference submission = reddit.submission("https://www.reddit.com/r/diabetes/comments/9rlkdm/shady_insurance_work_around_to_pay_for_my_dexcom/");
```

to this

```
SubmissionReference submission = reddit.submission("9rlkdm");
```

where the id is the random string after `/comment/` in the URL.

Hope this helps.